# Jmeter distribtion testting on linux

Tags: jmeter

I am trying do distributed testing on linux server using apache-jmeter 2.9

The default port (1099) is already used(by jboss)
I changed the port as 1097
I start jmeter-server on one machine for now and start test on single machine.

jmeter-server seems to start succesfuly 
but when evern i trying to exceute script is shows following error.

```
[jboss@StagingSvr2 bin]$ ./jmeter -n -t CBL_Load/CBL_Admin_Load.jmx -l
.jtl -R 172.16.0.2
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using CBL_Load/CBL_Admin_Load.jmx
Configuring remote engine for 172.16.0.2
Failure connecting to remote host: 172.16.0.2
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
Failed to configure 172.16.0.2
[![enter image description here][1]][1]No remote engines were started.
```

I have gone through google but not able to find exact solution that where I am doing blundder!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure nothing is listening at the port `1097` using [netstat](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-netstat-command-examples/) or [nc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-netcat-to-establish-and-test-tcp-and-udp-connections-on-a-vps) or [telnet](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-telnet/). Looking into `non-JRMP server at remote endpoint` something is present there which is not JMeter RMI endpoint. Try locating a free port using aforementioned tools and bind JMeter slave to it
2. With regards to `bind JMeter slave` I would recommend amending your startup command to something like:

   ```
   ./jmeter-server -Dserver_port=xxxx
   ```

   where `xxxx` is a free port on your Linux system
3. Amend your Master startup command to include the port as well like:

   ```
   ./jmeter -R 172.16.0.2:xxxx -n -t CBL_Load/CBL_Admin_Load.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

More information:

- [JMeter Remote Testing: Using a different port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. this helps and resolve my problem if I am running test in one machine. as you seen in my question. but if I am running in real distributed mode giving another exception.

Comment: The second error indicates that you're missing [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) plugin on the slave machine. You will need to install it (as well as any other plugins) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Correct.It was missed by me.Test got started but nothing write on .jtl file and also showing Active Users as 0.How to resolve this

Comment: Oh,there was some mistake to refering .jtl file.this is working fine for now